# VR video no longer showing on any device

Tags: wordpress, video, mp4, virtual-reality

My hosting had a problem and they were down for a few hours. When they got back the videos were no longer showing (desktop or mobile). It worked without an issue for months. I didn't changed anything on site, except the regular updates on wordpress and plugins.

I did all that I could think. Cleaned cache in plugin, in panel, checked code, tried different php versions, deactivate plugins one by one and cleaned cache.

The support suggested this solution: https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Still not working.

To make things interesting, the same code used on other sites on other hosting services are working.

Now their reply is something like:
"
I have re-checked this with out technical team, and we noticed that needed element for the video is located in source code, however, the source code doesn't load up.
I have to note, that we specialise in hosting-related issues, so I wouldn't be able to help you out with the code.
"

My code looks like this:

```
<dl8-video title="TiTlE" autr="xxxx" format="STEREO_180_LR" poster="https://cdn.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/xxxxxxx.jpg" preload="auto"><source src="https://mov.vrbangers.com/vrb_teachers_pet/VRBANGERS_teachers_pet_trailer_HQ_180x180_3dh.mp4"></dl8-video>
```

(website [link](https://vrselector.com/) is nsfw!)

Video source is on another website.

Anyone has any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: `video no longer showing on any device` but never a link to test... Either make a demo page showing problem in action or provide a temporary link to an MP4 so we test if it really does not show _"on any devices"_ as you say.

Comment: `https://mov.vrbangers.com/vrb_teachers_pet/VRBANGERS_teachers_pet_trailer_HQ_180x180_3dh.mp4`  (nsfw link). The link on it's own works.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the conflict. It was the newest version of [**wp-rocket**](https://wp-rocket.me/) cache plugin.

**Solution**:
I deactivated it and also cleaned cache from hosting panel. After a few hours the videos are showing again on all devices (desktop, mobile, tablets, app) and on all major browsers.

on the side topic: I sent the details to wp-rocket. Hope they can solve it and I can re-activate it, as it is a paid plugin.